# How to prove this series Cauchy product?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, power-series, cauchy-product

Let the first series be $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} u_{k}(x-a)^{k}$.

Let the second series be $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} v_{k}(x-a)^{k}$

Their convergence areas are $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$.

I don't know how to prove that $f(x)*g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} w_{k}(x-a)^{k}$, where $w_{k}=\sum_{k} u_{k} v_{k-n}$ and that its convergence area is $R\geq\min{R_{1},R_{2}}$.

I thought about the convergence area so that if the smallest convergence area is 0, then R must be greater or equal than it. But I don't know how that helps me or how to prove anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $w_k=\sum_{n=0}^ku_nv_{k-n}$, then\begin{align}w_k(x-a)^k&=\sum_{n=0}^ku_nv_{k-n}(x-a)^k\\&=\sum_{n=0}^ku_n(x-a)^nv_{k-n}(x-a)^{k-n}.\end{align}So, $w_k(x-a)^k$ is the $k$<sup>th</sup> term of the Cauchy product of the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty u_k(x-a)^k$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty v_k(x-a)^k$. So, if $|x-a|<R_1$ and $|x-a|<R_2$, the series$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty w_k(x-a)^k$$converges, since it is the Cauchy product of two absolutely convergent series. Therefore, the radius of convergence is at least $\min\{R_1,R_2\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can I ask more about the $w_{k}=\sum_{0}^{k} u_{n}v_{k-n}$ bit? How can I arrive at that with the information given, because that's also a part of the problem?

Comment: Because that's how $w_k$ is defined.

Comment: Got it, so there simply is no proof for it? It's not like a Lemma or a Theorem? Sorry, if I seem obtuse.

Comment: There is no simple proof for *what*? I thought that I proved whatever I should have proved in my answer.

Comment: I also think the proof needs to include the part where it's explained why $w_{k}$ is defined the way it is by the series one & two. Why for example is it that $w_{k}=\sum_{n=0}^{k} u_{k} v_{k-n}$. Is there an explanation as to why for example the indexes go $k-n$?

Comment: That part is also necessary and I thought I mentioned that in the question, too.

Comment: Again, that's how $w_k$ is *defined*.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sincerely grateful!